# React-Native: Type Error when parsing JSON

Tags: json, react-native, axios

I was trying to implement a News App. It should show a list of news headlines on start with thumbnail image and description and then on clickinh the url should be opened in browser. But, i am stuck on halfway getting a Type Error.

Here are the codes of my NewsList and NewsDetail files.

NewsList.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { ScrollView } from 'react-native';
import axios from 'axios';
import NewsDetail from './NewsDetail';

class NewsList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
          news: []
        };
    }
    //state = {news: []};
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey=MYAPIKEY')
        .then(response => this.setState({news: response.data }));
    }

    renderNews() {
        return this.state.news.map(newsData => 
        <NewsDetail key={newsData.title} newsData={newsData} />
     );

    }

    render() {
        console.log("something",this.state);
    return (
        <ScrollView>
            {this.renderNews()}
        </ScrollView>

    );
    }
}

export default NewsList;
```

NewsDetail.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View, Image, Linking } from 'react-native';
import Card from './Card';
import CardSection from './CardSection';
import Button from './Button';
import NewsList from './NewsList';

const NewsDetail =({ newsData }) => {
    const { title, description, thumbnail_image, urlToImage, url } = newsData;
    const { thumbnailStyle, 
        headerContentStyle,
        thumbnailContainerStyle,
        headerTextStyle,
        imageStyle } =styles;
 return(
     <Card>

         <CardSection>
             <View>
                 <Image 
                 style={thumbnailStyle}
                 source={{uri: urlToImage}}
                 />
             </View>
             <View style={headerContentStyle}>
                 <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{title}</Text>
                 <Text>{description}</Text>
             </View>
         </CardSection>

         <CardSection>
             <Image
             style={imageStyle} 
             source={{uri:urlToImage}}
              />
         </CardSection>

         <CardSection>
             <Button onPress={() =>Linking.openURL(url)} >
             ReadMore
             </Button>
         </CardSection>

     </Card>
 );
};



export default NewsDetail;
```

StackTrace of the Error i am getting

> TypeError: this.state.news.map is not a function
>
> This error is located at:
>       in NewsList (at App.js:11)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:78)
>       in View (at App.js:9)
>       in App (at renderApplication.js:35)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:78)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:102)
>       in RCTView (at View.js:78)
>       in View (at AppContainer.js:122)
>       in AppContainer (at renderApplication.js:34) NewsList.renderNews
>       NewsList.js:21:31 NewsList.proxiedMethod
>       createPrototypeProxy.js:44:29 NewsList.render
>       NewsList.js:31:18 NewsList.proxiedMethod
>       createPrototypeProxy.js:44:29 finishClassComponent
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8707:30 updateClassComponent
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:8674:11 beginWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:9375:15 performUnitOfWork
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11771:15 workLoop
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:11839:25 Object.invokeGuardedCallback
>       ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:39:9

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, View } from 'react-native';
import Header from './header';
import NewsList from './NewsList';

//create component
const App = () => {
    return(
    <View style={{ flex:0 }}>
        <Header headerText={'Headlines'} />
        <NewsList />
    </View>);
}

export default App;
AppRegistry.registerComponent('news', () => App);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you're getting - `TypeError: this.state.news.map is not a function`, means that news is not an array.
By checking your api response you should do:
 `this.setState({news: response.data.articles })`.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually go to https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=in&apiKey="MY_API_KEY" in the browser or use a tool like `curl` or Postman to check what the response is. The data response is an object, but you need an array. `articles` is most likely the property you are after.

You may also want to check that this is an array and update what is displayed appropriately.

```
.then(response => {
  const news = response.data.articles;
  if (Array.isArray(news)) {
    this.setState({ news });
  } else {
    this.setState({ errorMessage: 'Could not load any articles' });
  }
});
```